# Is there a SQL query that can perform this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set that is many years of data with millions of rows.

I am looking for a query that will return a sample amount of each DAY for all of that time.

For instance grab the first 1000 rows for each date day would work, but it would be better if it was not the FIRST 1000 rows but a random 1000 rows in that day or at least spread out enough that it would cover many hours of that day so it would be an accurate representation of that day.

This query involves intimate knowledge of dates in SQL which is one of my weak points.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(date_col order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 1000;
```